# Mismatch between number of review queues in header and actual queues

Tags: support

Why do I see 5 posts to review in my writers.SE header, but there are none in the queues?

[image]

Comment: I'd also like to know the answer to this. I've seen it for some time.

Comment: According to one of the developers [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237873/162102), the number in the header is heavily cached.  But there's more going on that just that; I've seen the number be wrong for days on end.